# PHP MySQL: How to retrieve all images associated to an item id from images table

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

So I have two tables.

Items table:

```
+---------+-----------+
| item_id | item_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Item One  |
|       2 | Item Two  |
+---------+-----------+
```

Images table:

```
+---------+----------------------+
| item_id |      item_image      |
+---------+----------------------+
|       1 | clofr9ohuvex5cxeyrfm |
|       1 | slnorjbqfd2x7ks0marp |
|       1 | oomkjtomvasklx9be4sq |
|       2 | um8donrpeuvfrmqb7qt  |
|       2 | lowcvoaijxniiqdj5eoe |
|       2 | qwxfartcsdyusw4lrngi |
+---------+----------------------+
```

My php code to get list of items with their associative images:

```
$itemsQuery = $db->prepare("
        SELECT *
        FROM items a,item_images b
        WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id
    ");
    $itemsQuery->execute();
    $items = $itemsQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($items);
```

I am getting 6 results instead of 2.

What I want is to show the 2 items present in the "items table" with their associative images from the "images table" based on the item_id.

I can query the "items table" and loop through it to query the database one more time to get the images. But how can I do it in one database call?

Comment: Since each Item_id having 3 item_image, you get 6 results.

Comment: @RavinderReddy How would I go about getting the 2 items with their associative images instead?

Comment: what are the associative images you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get MySQL to group all the values from the second table to a single column for you:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.item_image) AS item_images
FROM
    items a,item_images b
WHERE
    a.item_id = b.item_id
GROUP BY
    a.item_id
```

The result will be a key named `item_images` that contain each `item_image` for that `item`, separated by `,`:

```
um8donrpeuvfrmqb7qt,lowcvoaijxniiqdj5eoe,qwxfartcsdyusw4lrngi
```

You can then use `explode` on the PHP side if you want it as an array instead.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks you loads!